# Set value to FormControl Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having some 60 properties and mapped them to 60 controls using `mat-tab` in a form. Now for the edit mode i have to set values to all the controls.

Found this way,

```
this.form.controls['dept'].setValue(selected.id);
```

Finding each control and assigning the value.

Is there anyway like,

```
this.form.setValue(modelName);
```

Or a kind of more easier way for me to set the values instead of writing 60 lines of code?

I have used `ReactiveForms`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite figure out what your model and control relationship is, but you could try looping through the keys of the form controls and setting the values appropriately, like this:

```
const keys = Object.key(this.form.controls);

keys.forEach((key: string) => {
  this.form.controls[key].setValue(model[key]);
});
```

Or if you're already creating the controls in a loop, just set the values at time of creation.

This article helped me do this exact thing: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Comment: this helped me well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use patch value like this:

```js
let obj = {
  dept: 'abc'
};

this.form.patchValue(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model properties are same as your form attributes(model is completely mapped to the form) then you can use the [`setValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue) method of the [Raactive Form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Your code will be like this:

```
this.form.setValue(yourModelObject)
```

This will assign all your model attributes to your form attributes.